# GCM data not being passed by AWS SNS

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, google-cloud-messaging

I'm using Amazon SNS to send push notifications to an Android device. If I send the following JSON I can't read the parameters in the data element.

{
    "default": "message here",
    "GCM": {
        "data": {
            "message": "This is the message"
        }
    }
}

I can read the default element but in my broadcastreceiver I can't do this.

protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

```
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();

    Log.d("GCM",extras.getString("message");
```

}

Trying to read the message element causes an error.

If I send directly through GCM I can read all of the parameters that start with data. using the above method with no problem at all.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Dump the contents. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5968896/listing-all-extras-of-an-intent.

Comment: Received: Bundle[{from=xxxxxxxxxxxx, default=message here, android.support.content.wakelockid=1, collapse_key=do_not_collapse}]

Answer (score 1):

You need escape double quotation in GCM value.

```
{ "default": "message here", "GCM": "{ \"data\": { \"message\": \"This is the message\" } }" }
```