# How do I print the contents of an Intent for logging purposes?

Tags: android

Have you written a utility to print all parameters of an intent? Like...

```
Intent i = ...    
Log.d(tag, "INTENT = " + Util.printIntent(i) );
```

**including target, extras, data, etc** ?   Thanks for the help.

UPDATE:
What I have so far ...

```
if (G.DEBUG) Log.d(U.getTag(), "INTENT = " + intentToString(intent)  );

public static String intentToString(Intent intent) {
   if (intent == null) {return null;}
   String out = intent.toString();
   Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
   if (extras != null) {
       extras.size();
       out += "\n" + printBundle(extras);
   }
   if (intent.getAction() != null)     out+="\nAction = " + intent.getAction();
   if (intent.getType() != null)       out+="\nType = " + intent.getType();
   if (intent.getData() != null)       out+="\nData = " + intent.getData();
   if (intent.getPackage() != null)    out+="\nPackage = " + intent.getPackage();
   if (intent.getDataString() != null) out+="\nDataString = " + intent.getDataString();
return out; 
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use the debugger? It's way easier and more universal

Comment: see `toUri(int flags)` method

Comment: @pskink:  The URI contains the Intent's data as the base URI, with an additional fragment describing the action, categories, type, flags, package, component, and extras.    That looks perfect, however... how do I get the "additional fragment?" I just get ... "intent:#Intent;component=com"

Comment: @ Robin Kanters: Just personal preference, I like to watch logs. :) They remind me of my programs flow of execution and usually serve as good places to write tests when I'm done. That said, I could probably take your advice more often... maybe I would get faster using it.

Comment: I tried all the flags. All I ever get is the target class. The doc says there is an "additional fragment" with all the good stuff. How do you get to it?

Comment: see [this](http://androidxref.com/5.1.1_r6/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/content/Intent.java#7288)

Comment: @kandinski The additional fragment is actually the part "describing the action, categories, type, flags, package, component, and extras", so actually most of the output of the _toUri_ method. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39543548/220039) for an example.

Comment: see answers here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5968896/listing-all-extras-of-an-intent

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `Intent#toString()` method works pretty good, it will print most stuff but it doesn't print the extras unfortunately. The extras are in a `Bundle` that can also be printed with `Bundle#toString()` but if the Intent just arrived from another process then the contents of the extras `Bundle` won't be printed until you trigger it to be unparcelled, also it doesn't properly print lists or arrays. This code below should help print out just about everything:

```
public static String intentToString(Intent intent) {
    if (intent == null) {
        return null;
    }

    return intent.toString() + " " + bundleToString(intent.getExtras());
}

public static String bundleToString(Bundle bundle) {
    StringBuilder out = new StringBuilder("Bundle[");

    if (bundle == null) {
        out.append("null");
    } else {
        boolean first = true;
        for (String key : bundle.keySet()) {
            if (!first) {
                out.append(", ");
            }

            out.append(key).append('=');

            Object value = bundle.get(key);

            if (value instanceof int[]) {
                out.append(Arrays.toString((int[]) value));
            } else if (value instanceof byte[]) {
                out.append(Arrays.toString((byte[]) value));
            } else if (value instanceof boolean[]) {
                out.append(Arrays.toString((boolean[]) value));
            } else if (value instanceof short[]) {
                out.append(Arrays.toString((short[]) value));
            } else if (value instanceof long[]) {
                out.append(Arrays.toString((long[]) value));
            } else if (value instanceof float[]) {
                out.append(Arrays.toString((float[]) value));
            } else if (value instanceof double[]) {
                out.append(Arrays.toString((double[]) value));
            } else if (value instanceof String[]) {
                out.append(Arrays.toString((String[]) value));
            } else if (value instanceof CharSequence[]) {
                out.append(Arrays.toString((CharSequence[]) value));
            } else if (value instanceof Parcelable[]) {
                out.append(Arrays.toString((Parcelable[]) value));
            } else if (value instanceof Bundle) {
                out.append(bundleToString((Bundle) value));
            } else {
                out.append(value);
            }

            first = false;
        }
    }

    out.append("]");
    return out.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 6):

The simplest one:

```
 public static String intentToString(Intent intent) {
    if (intent == null)
        return "";

    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder("action: ")
            .append(intent.getAction())
            .append(" data: ")
            .append(intent.getDataString())
            .append(" extras: ")
            ;
    for (String key : intent.getExtras().keySet())
        stringBuilder.append(key).append("=").append(intent.getExtras().get(key)).append(" ");

    return stringBuilder.toString();

}
```

Comment: But this doesn't include the category and flags, and the easiest way to log those is to just use intent.toString, so I think it is just the extras bundle that requires special handling.