# Print data in table using for loop in android

Tags: java, android

I have just get the data from another activity using the following code,

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
Bundle data = intent.getExtras();
String LnAmt = data.getString("Amount");
String IntRate = data.getString("Rate");
String LnPrd = data.getString("Period");
```

I want to print these data in table using for loop. But i don't understand how to print. Please help me to print those value in table.

Comment: for loops works for an array. So how would you loop for displaying it. The above are String Values.

Comment: Do you want to print it in tableLayout or in list if you want to display it inside the tableLayout so here is the example https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_table_layout.htm

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5968896/listing-all-extras-of-an-intent

Comment: Question is confusing it seems , you can loop through the List/Array or other structures but you are passing String data through intent which is linear, If you have List/Array to represent in a tabular form than you can have a table layout to represent or a RecyclerView.