# Check if the user has signed in for the first time or not, using Firebase AuthUI

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

I know that in the basic firebase authentication I can use `AdditionalUserInfo.isNewUser()` method in the `OnCompleteListener.onComplete` callback to see if the user is new or not. But, how do I get it done using the new pre-built FirebaseUI for authentication?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since FirebaseUI is simply a UI built on top of Firebase, the two can be used together without problems. But unfortunately the `AdditionalInfo` can only begotten from an `AuthResult`, which is only available when the user actively signs in, e.g. [`signInWithEmailAndPassword`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuth.html#signInWithEmailAndPassword(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)). It looks like there is no way to get it from an AuthStateListener

As @bojeil said in the comments, a less reliable way that may work is to check the value of `metadata.getCreationTimestamp()` and `metadata.getLastSignInTimestamp`. If those are the same, the user was just created. For an example of this, see the [FirebaseUI documentation](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/tree/master/auth#user-metadata).

Comment: Can you share an example code? That would be really helpful

Comment: Hmmm.... as far as I can see you can only get the `AdditionalInfo` from an `AuthResult`, which is only available when the user actively signs in, e.g. `signInWithEmailAndPassword`: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuth.html#signInWithEmailAndPassword(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String). So it looks like there is no way to get it from an `AuthStateListener`.

Comment: One less reliable way of doing this is checking https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseUser.html#getMetadata(). It gives you access to the user creation and sign in time. You could use that to compute if the user is new or existing.

Comment: Here is the link in FirebaseUI: https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/tree/master/auth#user-metadata

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Those 2 values were returning timestamps 2 milliseconds apart for Google sign-in on my device. It's not reliable.

Answer (score 3):

In my last try to get the result of `isNewUser()` with Firebase simple UI. I did print all of `Intent data` in `protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)` by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15074150/5873832) in which we can realise that `data` contains a IdpResponse ParcelableExtra that have `isNewUser()` value.

```
IdpResponse idpResponse = data.getParcelableExtra("extra_idp_response");
Log.e("TAG", "isNewUser= " + idpResponse.isNewUser());
```